# Javascript to mute embedded mp4 when YouTube video plays?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I'm looking to mute an embedded mp4 video when a YouTube video begins playing – I'm using a Wordpress template similarly setup to this [site](http://www.cobuilt.com/); however, the video that would be in the background on the homepage has audio that can toggle on/off. If it's on, I want that audio to mute when a modal opens for one of the YouTube videos setup in a flickity carousel.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add in source URL as a GET parameter "?mute=1",

also Like that

```
iframe.getElementById('video').mute();
```